# Change value of input using Selenium

Tags: selenium, date, input, selenium-ide

I'm using Selenium IDE to fill out a form. It's not my website, so I cannot change the code. I've managed to do most of the things, the only input I'm struggling to put the data on is this one, which uses a datepicker/calendar instead of the a "traditional" input:

[image]

```
<input class="rich-calendar-input " id="dtEmissaoInputDate" maxlength="10" name="dtEmissaoInputDate" onkeypress="IsNumber(this,event);mascaraData(this,event);" size="15" style="vertical-align: middle; " type="text" value="09/10/2019" readonly="readonly">
```

Since I'm new to Selenium, I'd like to know how to change the value of that input using the data I have on an array. I've already searched older questions to see what I could find, but most of the answers use older syntax.

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Javascript to accomplish this. You can call `executeScript` to modify the `value` attribute of your desired element.

```
executeScript("document.getElementById('dtEmissaoInputDate').setAttribute('value', 'yourTextHere')");
```

You can also pass the element in directly:

```
executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', 'yourTextHere')", inputElement);
```

Hope this helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Based on @Christine's answer, I was to solve the issue using Javascript and run script command:

"command": "runScript",
"target": "document.getElementById('dtEmissaoInputDate').value='01/01/2018'",